# Sort a linked list with merge sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, mergesort

This is my version of a linked list in C. The function `mergeSort` requires a reference to the first and to the last nodes, as well as the indices of the first and the last node and a comparator.

You need to compile this source code using C99 standard in order to get it working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List {
    int val;
    struct List *next;
} List; 

List *new(int value)
{
    List *list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->next = NULL;
    list->val = value;

    return list;
}

void freeList(List *list)
{
    List *node = list;
    while(node != NULL) {
        List *n = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = n;
    } 
}

void print(List *list)
{
    for(List *node = list; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
        printf("%d ", node->val);        
    }
    printf("\n");
}

List *merge(List *part1, List *part2, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    List *temp;

    if(cmp(&part1->val, &part2->val) < 0) {
        temp = part1;
        part1 = part1->next;    
    }   
    else {
        temp = part2;
        part2 = part2->next;
    }

    List *current = temp;

    while(part1 != NULL && part2 != NULL) {
        if(cmp(&part1->val, &part2->val) < 0) {
            current->next = part1;
            part1 = part1->next;
        }
        else {
            current->next = part2;
            part2 = part2->next;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    while(part1 != NULL) {
        current->next = part1;
        current = current->next;
        part1 = part1->next;
    }

    while(part2 != NULL) {
        current->next = part2;
        current = current->next;
        part2 = part2->next;
    }

    return temp;
}

List *mergeSort(List *start,
                List *stop,
                int startIndex,
                int stopIndex,
                int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    if(start != stop) {
        int mid = (startIndex + stopIndex) / 2;
        int i = startIndex;

        List *midNode = NULL;
        for(List *node = start; node != stop; node = node->next) {
            if(i == mid) {
                midNode = node;
            } 
            i++;
        }
        List *midNodeNext = midNode->next;

        List *part1 = mergeSort(start, midNode, startIndex, mid, cmp);
        List *part2 = mergeSort(midNodeNext, stop, mid + 1, stopIndex, cmp);

        return merge(part1, part2, cmp);
    }

    start->next = NULL;
    return start;
}

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return *(int *)a - *(int *)b;
}

List *push(List *list, List *node) 
{
    List *last;
    for(List *node = list; node != NULL; node = node->next) {
        if(node->next == NULL) {
            last = node;
        }
    }
    last->next = node;

    return node;
}

int main()
{
    List *list = new(9);

    push(list, new(4));
    push(list, new(3));
    push(list, new(2));
    push(list, new(1));
    List *stop = push(list, new(8));

    list = mergeSort(list, stop, 0, 5, cmp);

    print(list);

    freeList(list);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `new()` is not a great name for a function. Maybe `newNode()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Merging tails effectively wastes cycles. The nodes are already linked correctly.

  ```
      if (part1 != NULL) {
          current->next = part1;
      }

      if (part2 != NULL) {
          current->next = part2;
      }
  ```

  is enough.
- A single most important feature of merge sort is stability: elements compared equal remain in the original order. A comparison

  ```
      if(cmp(&part1->val, &part2->val) < 0)
  ```

  makes your sort unstable. A correct comparison is either one of

  ```
      if(cmp(&part2->val, &part1->val) > 0)
      if(cmp(&part1->val, &part2->val) <= 0)
  ```
- Less indentation is easier to follow. I recommend to invert a recursion termination condition:

  ```
      if (start == stop) {
          start->next = NULL;
          return start;
      }
      ...
  ```
- Avoid naked loops. The

  ```
      for(List *node = start; node != stop; node = node->next) {
          if(i == mid) {
              midNode = node;
          }
          i++;
      }
  ```

  should be factored out into a function

  ```
      List * advance(List * start, int steps);
  ```